# Timer v/s thread.sleep in terms of cpu usage

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, timer, thread-safety

I am using DMX 512 conroller to send hex data to 3 serial ports with `while (true)` loop where I use multiple `Thread.Sleep(50)` multiple times which reduces CPU usage and gets stop working after few hours.

Here is my code:

```
public static GO () 
{
    try
    {
        dmx = new Dmx(2, 0);

        Thread mTh1 = new Thread(() => dmx.Start(RGBdata1, RGBdata2, RGBdata3)); 

        Global.tmrStarted = true;  // test it,ok

        mTh1.Start();
    }
}
```

This is my start method where I send data to 3 ports where I used the `Thread.Sleep()` method multiple times:

```
while (Global.tmrStarted)
{
    Break();
    Thread.Sleep(500); 
    if (m_port == null || m_port.IsOpen == false) return;
    m_port.Write(new byte[] { 0 }, 0, 1);
    SendData();


    Break1();
    Thread.Sleep(500); //uncommect this is you need, test
    if (m_port1 == null || m_port1.IsOpen == false) return;
    m_port1.Write(new byte[] { 0 }, 0, 1);
    SendData1();
    Break2();
    Thread.Sleep(500); //uncommect this is you need, test

    if (m_port4 == null || m_port4.IsOpen == false) return;
    m_port4.Write(new byte[] { 0 }, 0, 1);
    SendData2();

    Thread.Sleep(100);
}
```

Can anyone suggest me how can I make above program thread-safe or using timer?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's unclear what you're wanting given the code posted/questions asked. Unless the other functions in the `while` posted spawn other threads, then how is the code posted _not_ thread-safe and what threading issues are you having? Is your program exiting normally or is there an exception somewhere? Using a timer won't solve an exceptional issue and performance wise you'd have to test to see which fits your needs better...

Comment: This is just not making sense. Why, again, do you need this loop? Is this a continuous job?

Comment: @textechhelp,@T.S.Yes, this is a continuous job with while loop where I send hex data to 3 ports so used m_port,m_port1,m_port2 . I get an exception in job  after working for continuous 7-8 hours that more threads are in WaitHandle state which leads to CLR raise exception though debug Diagnostic tool.I google it and got to know timer is far better than thread as thread always creates new thread for every process and so accumulates memory.

Comment: tip: only one @tag per message works here. Now - you get it wrong. You can create a timer, set its interval and on `timer_elapsed` event do your job. This way you don't need any loops. Your timer periodically will trigger the method that does the sending. Google "c# timer.elapsed" this is all you need

Comment: @T.S I implemented it  and it works .but as my application runs 24 * 7 for sending data to serial ports ,it suddenly gets stopped without getting any error . I thought memory consumption or cpu usage would have been problem due to use of thread but even with timer is it causing usage.

Comment: Make sure you clean up any unmanaged code. Use `.Dispose` on disposables, etc. Look into Event Log for errors. You can also stop your timer for the duration while it processing your queue. Looks like you have different issue than using timer. Timer is one fine mechanism for you. Polish rest of your code